# node js call html and activate "filename".js from the html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

hello i have html (i call it "index.html" ) that inside he activate "someScript".js (i call it script.js) , now i want to call the index.html from node js ( i call it server.js) but when i call the index.html he doesn't activate the script.js . he only show me the content in html

```
//only displaying the "blaaaa" that in the index.html


//this is the **script.js** that i talked about
{
    // here i read my index.html
    var http = require('http');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var content;
    // First I want to read the file
    fs.readFile('./index.html ', function read(err, html) {
        if (err) 
{
          throw err;
        }
        content = html;


    http.createServer(function(request,response){
    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write(html);
    response.end();

    }).listen(8081);

    console.log("listening on oprt 8081");


    });
}  

    //if i activate directly the index.html its working but because i tried to activate it from the script it doesn't  work
    **index.html**

    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>  
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
            <script>
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="blankdiv"> blaaaa </div>


        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server will always return the content of `index.html`, so when the browser requests 
`script.js` from it, it gets another copy of `index.html`.

You need to look at [the URL being requested (`request.url`)](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) and serve up different content for different URLs.